# A regular insurance claimant is trying to hide three fraudant claims among seven genuine claims.

Tags: probability

A regular insurance claimant is trying to hide three fraudulent claims among seven genuine claims. The claimant knows that the insurance company processes claims in batches of five or in batches of 10. For batches of five, the insurance company will investigate one claim at random to check for fraud; for batches of 10, two of the claims are randomly selected for investigation. The claimant has three possible strategy:

(a) submit all 10 claims in a single batch

(b) submit two batches of five, one containing two frad. claims, the other containing one

(c) submit two batches of five, one containing three frad. claims, the other containing 0.

Please help me in finding the probablity of (b) and (c)

Comment: What was you method for (a)?

Comment: @Henry I found the probablity for not getting caught i.e genuine claim. I calculated as 7*6/10*9 and then I subtracted the answer from 1.

Comment: So for (b) and (c) do something similar for each batch and then multiply

Comment: @Henry for (c) -> Prob of not getting caught for first batch will be 2/5 and for second batch would be 5/5 right?

Comment: Yes - so the probability of not being caught is then $\frac25 \times \frac55=\frac25$

Comment: @Henry Thanks alot :)